# Unable to Update Mono to Version 5.18 on Debian 9.8

Tags: debian, apt, mono

I'm unable to update [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) from version 4.6.2 to 5.18.0 on Debian 9.8. I followed the instructions on the [download page](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian) on Mono's website but with no luck so far.

```
root@server ~ # mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (Debian 4.6.2.7+dfsg-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

root@server ~ # cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch main

root@server ~ # apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org stable/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org testing/updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Hit:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable Release
Hit:9 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
Hit:10 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable Release
Hit:11 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch InRelease
Hit:12 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

root@server ~ # apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libgd3/testing 2.2.5-5.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.5-5+0~20190119054529.2+stretch~1.gbp911a4a]
libsodium23/testing 1.0.17-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.17-0.1+0~20190131101845.5+stretch~1.gbp8cf594]
```

---

**Update 1**

Added `sudo apt install mono-devel mono-complete` output.

```
root@server ~ # sudo apt install mono-devel mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mono-complete is already the newest version (4.6.2.7+dfsg-1).
mono-devel is already the newest version (4.6.2.7+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

---

**Update 2**

`/var/lib/apt/lists/` only has `partial` directory which is empty.

```
root@server /var/lib/apt/lists # ls -al
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 12288 Feb 23 07:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Feb 22 20:38 ..
drwx------ 2 _apt root 12288 Feb 22 20:38 partial

root@server /var/lib/apt/lists # cd partial/

root@server /var/lib/apt/lists/partial # ls -al
total 24
drwx------ 2 _apt root 12288 Feb 22 20:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 12288 Feb 23 07:53 ..
```

Error on running `apt full-upgrade`.

```
root@server ~ # apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

I'm getting the same error after running `aptitude` as shown in the screenshot.

[image: aptitude]

---

**Update 3**

Added `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99server` output.

```
root@server /etc/apt/apt.conf.d # cat 99server
Acquire::PDiffs "false";
Acquire::Languages "en";
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

---

**Update 4**

When I try to force install Mono 5.18.0 using `sudo apt-get install mono-devel/stable-stretch` I get the errors shown below.

```
root@server ~ # sudo apt-get install mono-devel/stable-stretch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '5.18.0.240-0xamarin1+debian9b1' (Xamarin-Stable-Stretch:9.0/stable-stretch [all]) for 'mono-devel'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil : Depends: libmono-system-design4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 mono-devel : Depends: libmono-i18n4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-design4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 5.18.0.240-0xamarin1+debian9b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: msbuild but it is not going to be installed
 monodoc-manual : Depends: monodoc-browser but it is not going to be installed or
                           monodoc-http but it is not going to be installed or
                           monodoc-viewer
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: what's the output from `sudo apt install mono-devel mono-complete` ?

Comment: @MichaelD. I added the output to my question.

Comment: With a "dirty hack" attempt you could try to download all dep packages files  manually mentioned in Update 4 to a new folder and install them with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.  Maybe you need to run the command two or more times until all packages are installed because of a specific order / dependencies. Be warned, this could break things - always make backups.

Answer (score 0):

Without a closer examination of your apt configuration, it's difficult to propose a simple command set to overcome this issue. However, the [Debian reference card](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/refcard/refcard.en.pdf) mentions a couple logical next steps toward a solution.

1. `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` will remove all cached package lists from your configured sources and force your next invocation of `apt update` to retrieve the most current manifest from each remote server
2. `apt full-upgrade` applies advanced conflict resolution to the evaluation of available package versions and could produce a more aggressive combination of packages to upgrade
3. `aptitude` would allow you to inspect in detail all the versions of the packages you want that apt is aware of and the logic it's using in deciding to upgrade them or keep them back, as well as allowing you to substitute your judgment and resolve any conflicts as you see fit

Comment: I tried to run the commands you shared and looks like my `apt` configurations are messed up. I've added the output to my question under **Update 2**.

Comment: It's been some time since I switched from Debian to Ubuntu and they differ on this, but I believe Default-Release should be your distro's version codename, not the release path. Try backing up the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99server` file to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/.99server` and then edit the file to read:

`APT::Default-Release "stretch";`

If it resolves the issue you can safely delete the backup and if not, you can simply `sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/.99server /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99server` and continue in search of the proper solution.